# Cast string as "Column Reference" in HIVE SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a query that is meant to use bind values to retrieve information from a table and test if any field is NULL. The user enters a column name for the bind value and that column is then tested for any NULL values. Here is a simplified version of the query:

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN ISNULL(bind.value) 
      THEN 'PASS'
      ELSE 'FAIL'
   END AS Solution
```

This keeps returning 'FAIL' I think because ISNULL() is testing the column entered as a string. Instead, I need it to test the fields in the column, rather than the string holding the column's name. Is there anyway to cast this string as a reference or pointer (I know SQL doesn't have pointer but a pointer-like object) to the a column?

NOTE: When I replace bind.value with the column name it returns 'PASS.' I'm really trying keep this as dynamic as possible so  can utilize it with other tables without having to write a new query for each table I use this on.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are passing empty strings instead of NULL.

empty string `''` is not the same as `NULL` in Hive, add test for empty string:

```
SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN ISNULL(bind.value) OR cast(bind.value as string)='' THEN 'PASS'
      ELSE 'FAIL'
   END AS Solution
```

Comment: No, as mentioned in the note, if I pass in the name of the column directly (without using the bind value) then it woks fine.

Comment: then pass it without quotes. Better show your code, how do you pass it???

Comment: When the user enters the bind value it has to be in quotes so that it can be read into a SELECT statement with an alias. I pass in the column name 'table.company_code' into the bind value

Comment: It will not work if quoted because if quoted it is a string, not a column. the end.

Comment: You're 100% correct, that's my issue. I was trying to figure out if there was a way to "un-stringify" it and revert it back to a column reference. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I do not know how it is possible inside the sql code. Try to use another method of building sql string.

Comment: @Z0S0 The thing is that before you can call any function in SQL, the whole SQL should be parsed, validated, permission verified, execution plan built, etc and only after all these steps the query will be executed.